# Only show if parent is X px height/wide

Tags: css, background-image

Well this is probably not possible with CSS only but I just really dislike it to fix styles with JS. So I thought I'll ask SO.

So I have an container which has an background image. This container has a variable height from 50px to infinite in theory. When the containers height is higher than ~500px it looks very good. Below that value it looks really stupid.
So the question is:

Can I apply a rule which just sets `display:none` (or similar) when the parent element is smaller than x (500 in my case) px?

Comment: You can do it if the *window* is less then 500px

Comment: I understand it's not what you're looking for, but if the height is indeed variable (i.e. you can't know it in advance), it's important to note that the JS involved would be very terse and involve a single DOM lookup according to which a class will be added to the element.

Comment: You should include the whole necessary code related to the question inside your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With just CSS this would be impossible.

The only thing, to my knowledge in CSS that can act like this is @media but that can only get the viewport height (not a containers height).

Alternatives are using an easy JS function, using @media height of the viewport, or have a min-height for the image, or change the variable range from 50-infinity to 500-infinity;

Answer (score 0):

You can use @media queries in Css to load a bigger/smaller image depending on the device position or screen resolution. Also hide it if it's smaller than 500px using css `display:none;` if for example, the image is background-image of a div.

Some examples: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

(You can try it by resizing your browser and it should make what you want without JS).

Hope that helps!